# Is there a similar function just like onStopTrackingTouch of SeekBar with verticalSeekBar control in Android?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

The *VerticalSeekBar* control is a vertical seekBar, you can see more details at https://github.com/lukelorusso/VerticalSeekBar .

Is there a event function in *VerticalSeekBar* control just like *onStopTrackingTouch* in *SeekBar* control?

I hope to do something in *VerticalSeekBar* when I stop to thumb.

**Code A**

```
horizontalSeekBar?.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, i: Int, b: Boolean) {
                // Display the current progress of SeekBar
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {
                // Do something
            }

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {                
                requireContext().toast(seekBar.progress.toString() +"M")
            }
})


verticalSeekBar?.setOnProgressChangeListener { progressValue ->
      requireContext().toast(  progressValue.toString()+"X")
}
```

**Layout A**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/camera_ui_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/horizontalSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"

            android:background="@color/white"

            android:max="10"
            android:thumb="@drawable/ic_thumb"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/verticalSeekBar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <com.lukelorusso.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
            android:id="@+id/verticalSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:vsb_progress="2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: check https://github.com/lukelorusso/VerticalSeekBar/blob/master/verticalseekbar/src/main/kotlin/com/lukelorusso/verticalseekbar/VerticalSeekBar.kt

Comment: Thanks! Is there a sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an inspection of the code, it is clear that *VerticalSeekBar* does not provide all the functionality of [*SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener). Specifically, callbacks that mimic the functionaility of *onStartTrackingTouch()* and *onStopTrackingTouch()* are missing, although a progress change listener is supported.

You can, however, add this missing functionality by extending the *VerticalSeekBar* as follows:

```
class MyVerticalSeekBar(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : VerticalSeekBar(context, attrs) {

    private var mChangeListener: OnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener? = null

    fun setOnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener(listener: OnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener?) {
        mChangeListener = listener
        // We will use the progress listener as defined in VerticalSeekBar.
        if (listener == null) {
            super.setOnProgressChangeListener(null)
        } else {
            super.setOnProgressChangeListener { newProgress ->
                listener.onProgressChanged(this, newProgress, true)
            }
        }
    }

    // Spy on touch events targeting the vertical seek bar to handle
    // onStartTrackingTouch() and onStopTrackingTouch()
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (mChangeListener != null) {
            when (ev.actionMasked) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> mChangeListener?.onStartTrackingTouch(this)
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> mChangeListener?.onStopTrackingTouch(this)
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
    }

    interface OnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener {
        fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: MyVerticalSeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean)
        fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: MyVerticalSeekBar)
        fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: MyVerticalSeekBar)
    }
}
```

An example using *MyVerticalSeekBar* based upon the sample app in the GitHub repository for *VerticalSeekBar*:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mainVerticalSeekBar.progress = 75

        mainVerticalSeekBar.setOnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener(
            object : MyVerticalSeekBar.OnVerticalSeekBarChangeListener {
                override fun onProgressChanged(
                    seekBar: MyVerticalSeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean
                ) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "<<<<onProgressChanged (V)")
                    mainProgressValue.text = progress.toString()
                }

                override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: MyVerticalSeekBar) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "<<<<onStartTrackingTouch (V)")
                }

                override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: MyVerticalSeekBar) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "<<<<onStopTrackingTouch (V)")
                }
            }
        )

        mainProgressValue.text = mainVerticalSeekBar.progress.toString()

    }
}
```